# Add and configure SystemJS to Ionic2 TypeScript project

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, ionic2

How to add and configure `SystemJS` to my `Ionic2` `TypeScript` project?, when you create a simple `Angular2` `TypeScript` project you're able to use the System.config({...}) instruction, but when you create an `Ionic2` `TypeScript` project the `SystemJS` is not added, How can I add and use `SystemJS` to my project? What are the steps?

Thanks in advance.

P.S. Sorry for my english